# CSS issues in iOS Browsers

Tags: ios, css

I've been developing a website with a custom menu (ReactJS). But it doesn't work in Chrome and Safari on iOS.

Below is the code structure.

```
<Header>
    <TopNavigation />
    <MenuBox />
</Header>
<PageBody>
    <TextContainer />
<PageBody>
```

When menu box appears, it should cover the whole page. But on iOS, the `<TextContainer />` comes on top of the menu bar.

z-index of `<Header />` is higher than that of `<PageBody />`

[image]

Any advice on why this is happening and how to solve this would be great.

Comment: I like the illustration. Did you make it for the question?

Comment: Yes I did. Thought it would clarify the issue I have :)

Comment: Wish everyone follows the pattern of an illustration or a GIF here ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway couldn't find the reason to that behaviour in iOS. Then changed the layout and made it work.

```
<Header>
    <TopNavigation />
</Header>
<MenuBox />
<PageBody>
    <TextContainer />
<PageBody>
```